# IEEEtran for natbib gives: 'Author (Year)'

Tags: citing, natbib, ieeetran, ieee-style, cite-package

Using this thesis template: http://folk.ntnu.no/skoge/group/latex-for-phd-thesis/?C=N;O=D (found on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/ntnu-phd-thesis)).

Changed `\usepackage{natbib}` to `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`, and added F10-INTRO.tex containing:

```
\chapter{Beginnnnnnnnnnn}
    
Hello \citet{hopcroft2006automata} world.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{references} % references.bib
```

My references.bib:

```
@article{hopcroft2006automata,
    title={Automata theory, languages, and computation},
    author={Hopcroft, John E and Motwani, Rajeev and Ullman, Jeffrey D},
    journal={International Edition},
    volume={24},
    year={2006}
}
```

Unfortunately this leaves me with:

[image: ch1]

---

[image: bib]

---

## How do I get numerical IEEE style references?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Here's the answer, may be helpful for others:

## Solution:

### Before

```
%% In prelude of unedited template
\usepackage{natbib}%\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{;}

%% In content of unedited template
%Chapters
%\input{F10-INTRO}
```

### After

```
%% In prelude
%\usepackage{natbib}%\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{;}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}

%% In content of unedited template
%Chapters
\input{F10-INTRO}
```

### F10-INTRO.tex

```
\chapter{Beginnnnnnnnnnn}

Hello \cite{hopcroft2006automata} world.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}\bibliography{references}
```

## Outputs

[image: ch1]

[image: bib]